# Emit zero-width bash prompt sequence from external binary

Tags: bash, prompt

In bash, how do I encode zero-width sequences into PS1, when those sequences are coming from stdout of an external process or function?  How do I implement `writes-prompt-sequences-to-stdout` so that it can emit multi-colored text to the prompt?

`PS1='$( writes-prompt-sequences-to-stdout )'`

---

I know that, when writing a bash PS1 prompt, I must wrap zero-width sequences  in `\[` `\]` so bash can compute correct prompt width.

`PS1='\[\e[0;35m\]$ \[\e[00m\]'` bash does not print the `\[` `\]` and understands the prompt is only 2 characters wide.

How do I move those sequences into an external function?  The following does not work, my prompt looks like `\[\]$ \[\]`, even though I can run `render-prompt` and see it writing the correct sequence of bytes to stdout.

```
PS1='$( render-prompt )'
function render-prompt {
    printf '\[\e[0;35m\]$ \[\e[00m\]'
}
```

Moving the printf call into PS1 *does* work:

```
PS1='$( printf '"'"'\[\e[0;35m\]$ \[\e[00m\]'"'"' )'
```

I theorized, perhaps bash is scanning the PS1 string *before execution* to count the number of zero-width bytes.  So I tried tricking it by encoding [] sequences that aren't printed, but it correctly ignores the trick.

```
PS1='$( printf '"'"'$$$$$'"'"' '"'"'\[\e[00m\]'"'"' )'
```

## My question:

How do I write `\[` `\]` sequences to stdout from a function or binary that is invoked via PS1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.  Bash special-cases `\e`, `\[`, and `\]` within PS1.  It coverts `\e` to an escape byte, `\[` to a `1` byte, and `\]` to a `2` byte.  External commands must write `1` and `2` bytes to stdout.

According to ASCII, these encode "start of heading" and "start of text."

http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html

Here's a working example, which relies on printf converting `\` escapes within the first positional parameter into the correct bytes:

```
PS1='$( render-prompt )'
function render-prompt {
  printf '\1\033[0;35m\2$ \1\033[00m\2'
}
```

```
render-prompt | hexdump -C
```

```
00000000  01 1b 5b 30 3b 33 35 6d  02 24 20 01 1b 5b 30 30  |..[0;35m.$ ..[00|
00000010  6d 02                                             |m.|
00000012
```

Answer (score 1):

You correctly figured out the `\1`, `\2` and `\e`. But there's a better and more correct way to produce the sequences.

The `printf` command takes FORMAT as the first argument. This format consumes the subsequent arguments. So your function could be better written this way:

```
render-prompt () { printf "\1%b\2%s\1%b\2" '\e[0;35m' '$ ' '\e[00m'; }
```

The first argument is `"\1%b\2%s\1%b\2"` and this is the format. It's a good and logical place for `\1` and `\2`, which embrace the `%b` parameters. (The `%b`s are `\`-escaped strings and `%s` represents a standard string.)

The others are `'\e[0;35m'`, `'$ '` and `'\e[00m'`, which correspond to `%b`, `%s` and `%b` in the format. Here I'd put `\e`s, as they escape the `[` braces they precede.